# Is usage of DISTINCT redundant in a simple query with an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Does DISTINCT in a simple query with an aggregate function have any effect?

```
select DISTINCT salesperson, SUM(sales_amt) from sales GROUP BY salesperson
```

I realize there are more complicated queries where DISTINCT *can* have an affect, such as:

```
select salesperson, SUM(DISTINCT sales_amt) from sales GROUP BY salesperson
```

(support for that syntax by platform may vary)

But I want to confirm that in the simple query example, DISTINCT is redundant.

EDIT: fixed missing GROUP BY salesperson

Comment: The DISTINCT in the second clause would probably not be very useful in real life; If a salesman sold 1000 screwdrivers at 3.23 each, it would return 3 dollars and 23 cents.  It would be more useful if you wanted to count the customers per salesman like this:  `select salesperson, count(DISTINCT customer) from sales group by salesperson`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are missing `GROUP BY salesperson` (it's invalid in SQL Server if you omit the group by), the `DISTINCT` is redundant in your first query.  The `GROUP BY` effectively performs a `DISTINCT` here by aggregating `salesperson`.

```
select DISTINCT salesperson, SUM(sales_amt) from sales GROUP BY salesperson
```

And you are, as you've noted, correct that placement of the `DISTINCT` *inside* the aggregate `SUM()` may produce a different rowset.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the missing 'GROUP BY'

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT DISTINCT [Col1], [Col2], ..., [ColN] FROM [Table]`

Is the same as:

`SELECT [Col1], [Col2], ..., [ColN] FROM [Table] GROUP BY [Col1], [Col2], ..., [ColN]`

`DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` is shorthand for "I want to `GROUP BY` every column in my `SELECT`. So yes, I would say it is redundant if you already need a group by anyway (which you do if you're going to have an aggregate function in there).

Answer (score 1):

Neither queries you wrote will execute since you need to have the group by in order to return an aggregate (SUM()).  You'll need something like this:

```
SELECT SalesPerson
, SUM(Sales_AMT) AS SalesAmount
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY SalesPerson
```